# SSH and VNC work, but there is no connection to outside websites

Tags: pi-3, networking, ssh, ethernet, vnc

I just got a Raspberry pi 3B yesterday, and I've been planging around with it quite a bit. I did run into one issue: the pi can't connect to the outside internet.

I have the pi connected to my router with a cat7 ethernet cable. The cable works as it should when I plug it into my desktop. I am running Raspbian from an 8 GB sd card. I have the pi configured with a static IP address so I can easily establish an SSH connection. I can connect to it with SSH end VNC, but I can't access websites. When i try to ping www.google.com it returns:
[image: ping google.com]
However, when I ping my router's IP it does work.
When i ping other devices on my network it also doesn't work, but it doen not return an error. It just takes too long for my patience.
I have played around with the /etc/network/interfaces file. These are the contents: 
[image: Interfaces]

I also have one other issue, the pi wont connect to wifi through neither the grafical interface nor the command prompt. This is of course with the ethernet cable disconnected. It doesn't list any acces points in the grafical inteface, but it does list some acces point when I use *sudo iwlist wlan0 scan*

Can anyone help me fix this?

Sincerely,
Julian Sanders

Comment: "configured with a static IP address" **HOW? WHY?** (Most people get it wrong.) Don't paste images, they are very difficult to read, paste text. From what I can see you are using a non-standard networking setup. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: How did you setup your 'static' IP? at router or configure it at `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`? I suspect that your dns is not working, but can't help until you show us on how you configure your network.

Comment: I set up a static IP with /etc.dhcpsd.conf to make it easier to SSH into the py. That way I don't have to look up the IP every time. I removed what I changed in that file, and the issue with the outside internet connection over ethernet dissapeared, although I still can't connect to wifi networks.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off avoiding the static ip, and instead modify the hostname of your pi in `sudo raspi-config`.

You can check the `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` files to verify.

Then you can ssh using that hostname instead of the ip address.

```
$ ssh pi@hostname
```